# Placing Tkinter label inside a frame not working

Tags: python, tkinter, label, frame

I've been trying to place a Tkinter label inside of a frame but for some reason whenever I pack the label the frame disappears and only the label is shown, after I comment the pack method of the label the frame appears, I have already read the other similar questions but they don't seem to answer mine. Here's my code:

```
# Output label
    self.text = StringVar()
    self.frame2 = Frame(self.root, height=50, width=400, bg="green")
    self.frame2.place(x=181, y=265)
    self.out_lab = Label(self.frame2, fg="magenta", font=('Times', 20, 'bold'), textvariable=self.text)
    self.out_lab.pack(side='right')
    self.text.set("Are you ready ?")
```

Comment: Frames (and other widgets) shrink to fit their contents. There are lots of questions on this site related to this behavior.

Comment: Try adding `fill=BOTH, expand=1` in Frame constructor call. If it doesn't work, try adding, the line `self.frame2.pack_propogate(0)`   right after `frame.place()` call (it might be 1 instead of 0, I don't remember correctly )